# How to store multiple files in mysql database and upload folder when files come from android device

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store multiple files in mysql database when file come from android device. here are my code which upload single file but i want upload multiple file.

```
$file_path = "document/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['doc']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {   
}
```

Guys Help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What difference does it make if the file comes from an Android device?

Comment: how to store multiple file. when user send one by one file. not in array

Comment: You store them just like you'd store multiple files from any other source. You may want to clarify (edit) your question a bit.

Comment: @Markus AO is it not correct question.

Comment: Run all submitted files, then insert them each with their own row in your table. Better if you can update your post with what you have tried.